# How to configure common.loader property in catalina.properties file in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, catalina

I am upgrading an app with an embedded Tomcat 5.5.X to use Tomcat 7.0.X.  The app has a folder ${catalina.home}/common/lib containing .jar files that are shared across web apps.  If I change the common.loader property to include this directory as below:

common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/common/lib,${catalina.home}/common/lib/*.jar

I get class not found errors on loading some web apps.  The needed .jar files are in ${catalina.home}/common/lib. If I simply copy the .jar files from  ${catalina.home}/common/lib to ${catalina.base}/lib, every thing works as expected.  However, the location of ${catalina.home}/common/lib is referenced in scripts and code and is not easily changed.  So to get the app to work I seem to have to duplicate the collection of .jar files.

It is as if the additional directories in the common.loader property are ignored.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the catalina.properties file needs to be located in ${catalina.base} which, in this case, is different from ${catalina.home}.  For some reason, if one is not found you get the default path.